# Two Cassandra nodes with a replication factor of 2 yet different sizes in storage used

Tags: cassandra, opennms

We have OpenNMS sending graph data to our Cassandra/Newts cluster which is comprised of 2 Cassandra nodes. I've set the replication factor to 2 for the keyspace "newts".

I started the nodes at the same time and left them up for some time, i then ran "nodetool cfstats newts" on each node and both nodes have the exact same write count.

If i however go in to the data directory "/db/newts" of each node and run "du -h" i can see the following:

- Node1 storage used: 36K
- Node2 storage used: 12M

How can they differ in size if i set the replication factor to 2? I know that they're connected to the same cluster via "nodetool status" which is showing both nodes as "UN" (Up/Normal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cassandra data is not written directly to the hard drive, it lives in:

> Commit log >> Memtable >> SSTables

[Here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html) you can find a good documentation on how data is written.

You can run:

```
nodetool flush
```

which will flush the memtables into sstables. After that you should be able to see the same sstable size on both of your nodes.